# Custom Nuxt Error Page not rendering (always the default one) (Nuxt 3, Vue 3, Vite)

Tags: vuejs3, vite, nuxtjs3, custom-error-pages

I'm building a nuxt 3 app from scratch.
I'm in the beginning and I've just created the error.vue next to app.vue.
I have just one index.vue page in pages folder with hellow world.

My error-vue has the following code.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Dang</h1>
    <p>
      <strong>{{ error.message }}</strong>
    </p>
    <p>It looks like something broke.</p>
    <p>Sorry about that.</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// const error = useError();
export default {
  props: {
    error: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

When I navigate to a non existing page, thow, it shows me always the Default Nuxt 3 Error Page, and not my customized one.

Should I do anything further?
Launch the error in middleware or plugins?
I've tried to launch the throw createError({...}) in a plugin error-handler.js as the docs say, but it always shows the Default Error Page.

If not one has any idea, I believe the only option left would be doing manual redirections to a error.page inside pages.

Nuxt config goes like :

```
import svgLoader from "vite-svg-loader";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  srcDir: "src/",
  components: [
    {
      path: "~/components",
      pathPrefix: false,
    },
  ],
  nitro: {
    routeRules: {
      "/": {
        headers: {
          "Cache-Control":
            "max-age=120, public, stale-while-revalidate=10, stale-if-error=3600",
          "Content-Language": "fr",
        },
      },
      "/_nuxt/": {
        headers: {
          "Cache-Control":
            "max-age=120, public, stale-while-revalidate=10, stale-if-error=3600",
          "Content-Language": "fr",
        },
      },
      "/**": {
        headers: {
          "Cache-Control":
            "max-age=600, public, stale-while-revalidate=10, stale-if-error=3600",
          "Content-Language": "fr",
        },
      },
      "/_nuxt/**": {
        headers: {
          "Cache-Control":
            "max-age=600, public, stale-while-revalidate=10, stale-if-error=3600",
          "Content-Language": "fr",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  modules: [
    "@bootstrap-vue-next/nuxt",
    "nuxt-jsonld",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n",
    "@nuxt/devtools",
    "@pinia/nuxt",
  ],
  vite: {
    plugins: [svgLoader()],
  },
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  app: {
    head: {
      ...  
    },
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      ... 
    },
    private: {
      ...
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: In a Nuxt3 project, you only need to add error.vue in the root directory of the project (at the same level as app.vue). No additional configuration is required. I have tried your code and it works fine. Perhaps you should try restarting a clean project.

Comment: Yes, I've done that. A fresh project, just with the error.page added in the root. I've tried putting srcDir: "src/", in the config, adding the pages folder there too and no change, putting the error.vue inside pages too and no change. If I delete srcDir: "src/", from the config I just have a white page in the /fake-domain route. 
Do you know any github example that you could share with me just to copy the base code and see if it works ? I'm working with a Mac ( even if that is nothing to do  with the issue )

Comment: You can try this repo: https://github.com/tinawng/nuxt-tailwind-static-template
Note: Add error.vue at the same level as app.vue.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. My project is setup with 'srcDir: "src/"' same as yours. My app.vue is at the same level as the src folder, as this is how it was originally setup before I moved to the src folder. Placing the error.vue next to app.vue didn't work. What did work is moving error.vue into the src folder. Note my app.vue is still outside of src folder. This may or may not be correct. Regardless the doc's seem lacking as simply putting the error.vue along side app.vue may not always be correct.

Comment: Minor update to my last comment. Although the error.vue rendered after moving it to the /src folder, not all errors were rendering this page. If I want to an invalid route, e.g. /foo it would render the Nuxt default error page for a second then go blank. Moving the app.vue under the /src folder seems to have corrected that. Now having both app.vue and error.vue under /src appears to be working.

Comment: Another minor thing, the doc's say to import NuxtError from #app, but that didn't work for me. I had to change the import to: import type { NuxtError } from 'nuxt/app'; See docs here: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/error-handling. When the error.vue was outside the /src folder the #app import worked.

I'm no Nuxt 3.8.2